# Install VS Code extensions in another directory

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I have very little local disk storage and I need to install the VS Code extensions to another directory. Is it possible to do it? How can I do it?

Comment: What platform are we talking about? Windows/MacOS/*nix?

Comment: Answered on SO - see [settings - Is there a way to change the extensions folder location for Visual Studio Code? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40080793/is-there-a-way-to-change-the-extensions-folder-location-for-visual-studio-code)

Comment: General FYI, it's recommended to store user data on a partition other than `C:`, which also eliminates the need to backup user data if needing to do a clean install or Reset; to do so, go to each folder's _Properties_ → _Location_ tab within `%UserProfile%`

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by using Symlinks.

Symlinks, or symbolic links, are “virtual” files or folders which reference a physical file or folder located elsewhere, and are an important feature built in to many operating systems, including Linux and Windows.

A symlink is essentially a pointer to a file or folder located elsewhere, consumes little space and is very fast to create (compared to copying a file and its contents).

The syntax is simple:

`mklink /H Link Target`

/H means that you'll make a "hard" link, as opposed to a "soft" or "symbolic" link.

When you open a soft link to a folder, you will be redirected to the folder where the files are stored.  However, a hard link makes it appear as though the file or folder actually exists at the location of the symbolic link, and your applications won’t know any better.

https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/16226/complete-guide-to-symbolic-links-symlinks-on-windows-or-linux/